# DateTime ParseExact string was not recognize as a DateTime C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, format, default-value

I'm trying to parse string as DateTime but I'm getting an error. here my code

```
return DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The date and its format is got from DataBase as string and I'm trying to add it to a DataColumn DateTime data type.

What's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If that is the datetime why not just use DateTime.MinValue ?  example : MessageBox.Show(DateTime.MinValue.ToShortDateString());

Comment: I'm a bit confused... was the format string in this question edited to match the answer instead of describing the problem? If so, please revert the edit, so others have a chance of understanding the problem that was actually solved here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to parse the `DateTime` *exactly*, therefore the format has to be exact

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: thanks. Ive already found the problem. Even the format, the time must be 00:00:00 AM.

Answer (score 1):

You're using ParseExact, meaning you're specifying the whole format of the date and time - and the format specified is "dd/MM/yyyy", which covers "01/01/0001" but what does the poor function do with " 12:00:00 AM"? Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.

Also, it's almost always better to use the "Try" functions for parsing - in this case "TryParseExact"

Comment: Hey Vivek, the best Stack Overflow answers are useful to future visitors for years to come. If the link were to break, this may not be as helpful. Consider an [edit] to bring in the important points from the link. Good luck! :)